LDAPException(resultCode=8 (strong auth required), diagnosticMessage='BindSimple: Transport encryption required
Now I have following code to create a new connection:
        return LDAPConnection(opts, host, port).apply {
            connectionName = "foo-$userDn-$host-$port"
            processExtendedOperation(StartTLSExtendedRequest(SSLUtil(TrustAllTrustManager()).createSSLContext()))
            bind(userDn, password)
        }      

Now I want to switch to use LDAPConnectionPool.
I tried to do this:
        val simpleBindRequest = SimpleBindRequest(userDn, password)
        val exampleConnection = LDAPConnection(opts, host, port).apply {
            connectionName = "foo-$userDn-$host-$port"
            processExtendedOperation(StartTLSExtendedRequest(SSLUtil(TrustAllTrustManager()).createSSLContext()))
            bind(simpleBindRequest )
        }      
        val ldapConnectionPool = LDAPConnectionPool(exampleConnection , 1, 10)
        ldapConnectionPool.setBindRequest(simpleBindRequest)           

later in some piece of code I do the call fir the first time
connectionPool.getConnection()
and it works because it returns initially passed connection (exampleConnection )
but when I do a call
connectionPool.getConnection()

for the second time I get LDAPException:

LDAPException(resultCode=8 (strong auth required), diagnosticMessage='BindSimple: Transport encryption required.
', ldapSDKVersion=6.0.11, revision=8b21d0a4c6eb8b5c3e60a96fc3e9e13b9c2f650f)
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionPool.createConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1388)
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionPool.createConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1269)
at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionPool.getConnection(LDAPConnectionPool.java:1866)

I suppose that it is because of
 processExtendedOperation(StartTLSExtendedRequest(SSLUtil(TrustAllTrustManager()).createSSLContext()))

is not called
Is there way to fix it ?

Can you rerun with the following VM arguments -Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake and share the log output in your question?

@Hakan54 thank you but  I was able to find an answer(please take a look)

The correct way is:
val startTLSPostConnectProcessor =
            StartTLSPostConnectProcessor(SSLUtil(TrustAllTrustManager()).createSSLContext())
val ldapConnectionPool = LDAPConnectionPool(exampleConnection , 1, 10, startTLSPostConnectProcessor)
    

